# Algorithm to draw a 2D graph of bounds connecting points

Tags: algorithms

I have a list of triangles, facets of a 3D convex hull, and I'd like to represent the relations between those facets on a 2D diagram, a bit like a puzzle, where each face is (for matter of simplicity) a triangle.

- Points are connected to 3 to any superior amount of other points.
- I dont want to repeat any triangle twice.

The points come from a set of colorimetric measurements plotted in CIE XYZ linear colorspace. There are +- 60 points corresponding to real color measurements.
To find the "extreme colors", I decided to compute the convex hull on the points, keeping only the external surface made by them (a series of triangles, the "skin" of the colorspace).

Now I'd like to make a 2D "cartography" of this "skin" made of triangles, where I will simplify every triangle. The "map" would show all relations of proximity between color-points.

**I don't care the real distance between points, I'd like a 2D grid of points as "regular" as possible...**

As a first attempt, I took scissors and pencil and produce a "puzzle" that looks like **image 2**

illustration of the colorspace:
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Looks potentially interesting. I feel you're really going to need to provide a more clear description to receive a reasonable answer, though. Is this one particular convex polyhedron you're working with? If so, can you provide a description? Perhaps, the vertices in 3D that create the convex hull. Or, maybe you need a general procedure that will work for the convex hull of a random collection of points?  If so, how many points? How are they distributed?

Comment: Thanks, I added more details, hope it's clearer now

Comment: I removed "equilateral" since it's impossible